# Can two metals bond covalently?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

Can metal ions be engineered to behave like non-metals in terms of chemical properties (by supplying or removing electrons), would the altered metal ions bond covalently?

Would the ions be too unstable and begin to decay?

Comment: There are quite a lot covalently bound metals to metals already, and I do not understand what you mean with engineering metal ions; Could you exlain a little more?

Comment: some examples of these molecules and/or covalent networks would be appreciated. also by 'engineering' i mean creating an ion that behaves in a specific chemical manner due to the number of valence electrons it possesses by removing or adding electrons from the valence shell.

Comment: The most ready answer to this question is $\ce{Hg_2^{2+}}$ and other [polycations of mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_polycations).